# Can I Avoid Joining The Same Table 3 Times?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have this database schema on a Oracle 12c database :

[image: Database schema]

I'm trying to answer this question :

**What is the game in which Dallas Mavericks had the biggest percentage of successful 3-point shots ?**

I've managed to answer this question with this query:

```
SELECT HOME_TEAMS.TEAM_NAME                    "HOME TEAM",
       AWAY_TEAMS.TEAM_NAME                    "AWAY TEAM",
       GAMES.GAME_DATE                         "DATE",
       TEAMS.TEAM_ID                           "GENERIC ID",
       HOME_TEAMS.TEAM_ID                      "HOME_ID",
       AWAY_TEAMS.TEAM_ID                      "AWAY_ID",
       GAME_STATISTICS.X3POINTSHOTS_PERCENTAGE "3 POINTS PERCENTAGE"
FROM GAMES_TEAMS_STATISTICS
         INNER JOIN GAMES ON GAMES_TEAMS_STATISTICS.GAME_ID = GAMES.GAME_ID
         INNER JOIN TEAMS ON GAMES_TEAMS_STATISTICS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.TEAM_ID
         INNER JOIN TEAMS HOME_TEAMS ON GAMES.HOME_TEAM = HOME_TEAMS.TEAM_ID
         INNER JOIN TEAMS AWAY_TEAMS ON GAMES.AWAY_TEAM = AWAY_TEAMS.TEAM_ID
         INNER JOIN GAME_STATISTICS ON GAMES_TEAMS_STATISTICS.STATS_ID = GAME_STATISTICS.STATS_ID
WHERE TEAMS.TEAM_ACRONYM = 'DAL'
ORDER BY GAME_STATISTICS.X3POINTSHOTS_PERCENTAGE DESC
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

However, to answer this question , I join the teams table 3 times. Is there any way I can write this query **in a more efficient way , avoiding so many joins** ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `HOME_TEAM`and `AWAY_TEAM` columns from the `GAMES` table and add a `HOME_AWAY` flag column to the`GAME_TEAM_STATISTICS` table.

Right now, you need to code for an `ASSERTION` (because they do not yet exist) to ensure the `GAME_ID`+`TEAM_ID` combo in `GAME_TEAM_STATISTICS` matches the `GAMES.HOME_TEAM`/`GAMES.AWAY_TEAM` information.